# Maximo Create WO and Specs thru Enterprise Service

Tags: maximo, inbound

I need to create a work order and populate the specifications in Maximo using data collected in another software system. I have not been able to create the work order AND populate the specifications in the same call to an object structure.  So, I was going to create the work order in an exit class of the enterprise service.

Would the best practice be: 
1. To allow the specification data to then continue to process through to the object structure for update (after populating the fields with the newly created work order information)? 
2. To populate the specifications from the exit class, keeping every update in the same transaction?

If 2, what would then process through to the object structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Work order creation and populate the specifications in Maximo can be done is single call.

To achieve this you have to populate the `CLASSSTRUCTUREID` in the `WORKORDER` object and the specification in `WORKORDERSPEC` object.

The Structure looks something like below:

```
<max:WORKORDER>
    <max:SITEID>BEDFORD</max:SITEID>
    <max:CLASSSTRUCTUREID>1001</max:CLASSSTRUCTUREID>
    <max:WORKORDERSPEC>
        <max:ALNVALUE>123</max:ALNVALUE>
        <max:ASSETATTRID>TESTATTR</max:ASSETATTRID>
    </max:WORKORDERSPEC>
</max:WORKORDER>
```